# How to recover performance_schema after restoring from partial innobackupex backup?

Tags: mysql, percona, backup, xtrabackup

I am taking a partial backup from a Master server, which needs to be restored on a to-be slave server. I only need one of the databases, and the mysql database.

I am following instructions on https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/innobackupex/partial_backups_innobackupex.html

The command I'm using looks like this:

```
innobackupex --user=<the_user> --password --databases="<database_name> mysql" --slave-info /path/backup
```

The prepare command looks like this:

```
innobackupex --apply-log --export /path/backup
```

And then I

> Copy back the prepared backup to a “clean” datadir (in that case, make sure to include the mysql database).

MySQL starts fine, but **without a performance_schema** and with a lot of

> 588 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'' has the wrong structure

on its error log.

Any idea why this might happen, and how to get the performance_schema back?

Comment: Did you upgrade?  And not run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: No upgrade was performed. Only needed a specific schema on the target server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution requires running mysql_upgrade on the server that has been restored. As per the documentation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-build-configuration.html

> If you install MySQL over a previous installation that was configured without the Performance Schema (or with an older version of the Performance Schema that may not have all the current tables), run mysql_upgrade after starting the server to ensure that the performance_schema database exists with all current tables. Then restart the server.